# Domain index checking using Google API

Tags: php, arrays, indexing, google-api

I am trying to build  a web site where a user can enter their web site and check their indexed pages in Google.
Just like we do by `site:domain.com`.

I am using a Google API, here is the link to API (I know it's deprecated):

http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/services/search/web?v=1.0&q=

When I use a code like:

```
<?php  

function getGoogleCount($domain) {
    $content = file_get_contents('http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/services/' .
        'search/web?v=1.0&filter=0&q=site:' . urlencode($domain));
    $data = json_decode($content);
    return ($data->responseData->cursor->estimatedResultCount);
}

echo getGoogleCount('stackoverflow.com');

?>
```

It is good as far as I want to know about the result counts,
but the next thing I want is to list all the results on my we bsite. I am unable to grab the results because when we write:

```
$data->responseData->cursor->estimatedResultCount
```

It goes straight,
but when we try to get results. I don't know how to do it, just to print the idea:

```
$data->responseData->results->[url & title & content here]
```

Because here results is an array, and I don't know how can I store info in an array in this case.

Have been searching for a long time but can't find anything related.....

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The easiest way is to use:

```
$data = json_decode($content, true);
```

That will convert objects to normal associative arrays which are probably easier to handle.
Then you access your values by something like this:

```
$results = $data['responseData']['results']; //array
$googleCount = $data['responseData']['cursor']['estimatedResultCount'];
```

Then with the results you can do something like this:

```
foreach ($results as $result) {
    echo $result['title'].' -> '.$result['url'] . '<br />';
}
```

But of course if you don't like associative arrays and you prefer objects, you could do it also this way:

```
$data = json_decode($content);
foreach ($data->responseData->results as $result) {
    echo $result->title .' -> '.$result->url.'<br />';
}
```

If you want to check which properties has the $result, just use `print_r` or `var_dump`.

Comment: Thank You but I am unable to understand when you say
`$results = $data['responseData']['results']; //array`
I mean in which form it will store data? I can't `echo` this array

Comment: using this cause
`Fatal error: Cannot use object of type stdClass as array in /home/upocketm/public_html/www.funfeat.com/clients/api/check.php on line 7` where line 7 says ` $googleCount = $data['responseData']['cursor']['estimatedResultCount'];` Does it make any sense?

Comment: You cannot echo an array. You can use `print_r` to see what's stored in it and then you access values by keys as I shown in the example. You get this fatal error because you didn't pass `true` as a second parameter to the function `json_decode`. Please check my example carefully.